# Too many statistically significant results with propensity score weighting

Tags: statistical-significance, python, propensity-scores

I'm currently performing a drug-wide associatinon study (DWAS) in a population-based cohort, in which I'm iterating over commonly used drugs to assess whether they have an association with my outcome of interest. Given that medications are not randomly assigned, but rather prescribed for an underlying condition, we wanted to 'correct' for confounding by using inverse probability score weighting. We used age, sex and common diagnosis to generate the propensity scores and subsequently used that information to calculate a corrected odds-ratio for said drug and the outcome of interest (see code below).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

import statsmodel.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

for drug in drugs:
    X = df.drop([outcome_of_interest, drug_usage], axis = 1)
    y = df[drug_usage]

    model_prop = LogisticRegression()
    model_prop.fit(X, y)
    df['prop_scores'] = model_prop.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] #probability scores

    df['ATE'] = np.where(df[drug_usage] == 1, #calculate average treatment effect weights
                         1 / df['prop_scores'],
                         1 /(1 - df['prop_scores']))
     
    model_outcome = smf.glm( #Model to generate the OR, p-value etc.
                            formula = f'outcome_of_interest ~ {drug_usage}',
                            data = df,
                            family = sm.families.Binomial(),
                            freq_weights = np.asarray(df['ATE'])).fit()
```

My question is this: How can I test whether the propensity scores generated here make sense? Performing my analysis in this way leads to suspiciously many statistically significant results (around 70% of all drugs tested), even when correcting for multiple comparisons. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that this analysis is futile, as you are greatly underadjusting for confounding.  Adjusting for common diagnosis codes inadequately captures confounding.  You'd need measures of _extent_ of disease and a comprehensive comorbidity index in the model at the least.  And note that propensity scores are an [inefficient way](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity.html) to adjust for confounding.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @FrankHarrell. Including comorbidity scores and a measure of extent of disease are great suggestions. Regarding the comment on propensity scores: Would you have more trust in the analysis if I included the aforementioned variables (age, sex, common diagnoses, comorbidity index etc.) as covariates into the model instead?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes.  That's because covariate adjustment avoids the problem on non-collapsibility of odds and hazards ratios and allows the treatment effect to not be constant (by inclusion of interactions).  Then there is the significant efficiency gain by explaining more outcome variation with covariate adjustment.  PS deals only the with counfounding part of the analysis, not with outcome heterogeneity (different subjects having different susceptibility to bad outcomes).